# Selenium WebDriver POM Handling compound classes

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, nullpointerexception

I am new to selenium and I am facing this null pointer exception in my code,
Here is a class of one of my page object (Login Page).

```
package Pages;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import Lib.lib;

public class LoginPage extends lib{

    WebDriver driver;
    By loginLink = By.xpath("/html/body/nav/div/a[7]");
    By emailInput = By.name("email");
    By passwordInput = By.name("password");
    By signInBtn = By.className("btn btn-primary btn-lg");

    public LoginPage(WebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver=driver;
    }

    public void redirectToLogin()
    {
        driver.findElement(loginLink).click();
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(emailInput));
    }

    public void enterEmail(String email)
    {
        driver.findElement(emailInput).sendKeys(email);
    }

    public void enterPW(String password)
    {
        driver.findElement(passwordInput).sendKeys(password);
    }

    public void clickOnSignIn() throws Exception
    {
        driver.findElement(signInBtn).click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    }

    public void loginToKB(String userEmail, String userPW) throws Exception
    {
        this.redirectToLogin();

        this.enterEmail(userEmail);

        this.enterPW(userPW);

        this.clickOnSignIn();
    }

}
```

And this is my Test Case code

```
package TestCases;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import Lib.lib;
import Pages.LoginPage;

public class logging_in extends lib {
    LoginPage memLogin = new LoginPage(driver);

    @Test
    public void user_login() throws Exception
    {

        memLogin.loginToKB("uzii@test.com", "uziii");

    }

}
```

I am importing the chrome driver configuration from the lib class, which is following,

```
package Lib;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;

public class lib {

    protected static WebDriver driver = null;

    @BeforeTest
    public void chrome_extension()
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.get("http://www.testsite.com");
    }


    @AfterTest
    public void quit()
    {
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

When I am running my Test Case (logging_in), I initially redirect to website page, but after that it stops the execution and gives me compound class error.

Error seems to be pointed towards this,

By signInBtn = By.className("btn btn-primary btn-lg");

Please let me know, how to handle compound classes. Any help/feedback will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You have declared webdriver driver instance as private in class lib which is correct then your'e again declaring webdriver driver instance in class LoginPage which is incorrect.

Comment: @RupeshShinde Thanks a lot, that got resolved. Can you let me know how to tackle with compound class names. I am getting an error 

org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted

which seems to be this one,
By signInBtn = By.className("btn btn-primary btn-lg");

Any idea how to deal with these?

Comment: @Uziii please note if you wish to change the question then edit your original request else you will be flagged for asking questions in improper way

Comment: @MrunalGosar Will do that just now... Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are passing static driver instance without initialization to LoginPage(Webdriver driver) constructor. You would need to initialize the drive either in static block in lib or before initializing memLogin variable in logging_in page.
2. for compound classes you will have to use XPath. if you can show us html snippet of your DOM, we should be able to tell you the relevant XPath.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared *web-driver driver* instance as **private** in class lib which is correct then your'e again declaring *web-driver driver* instance in class *LoginPage* which is incorrect.

Remove the second declaration to avoid the null pointer exception.